# Push notification in cordova

Tags: android, cordova, push-notification, phonegap-plugins

I am using cordova plugin add phonegap-plugin-push --variable SENDER_ID=XXXXXXXX
this plugin. And added following code into javascript file.

```
   function setupPush() {
   var push = PushNotification.init({
       "android": {
           "senderID": "XXXXXXXX"
       },
       "ios": {
         "sound": true,
         "alert": true,
         "badge": true
       },
       "windows": {}
   });

   push.on('registration', function(data) {
       console.log("registration event: " + data.registrationId);
       var oldRegId = localStorage.getItem('registrationId');
       if (oldRegId !== data.registrationId) {
           // Save new registration ID
           localStorage.setItem('registrationId', data.registrationId);
           // Post registrationId to your app server as the value has changed
       }
   });

   push.on('error', function(e) {
       console.log("push error = " + e.message);
   });
 }
```

It gives error as "TypeError: Cannot call method 'init' of undefined".

Comment: Did my answer help your problem at all?

Answer (score 1):

This usually happens if you haven't done this after `onDeviceReady`. You can't access any native device APIs until after this fires (push notifications, camera, etc).

```
function onDeviceReady() {

    // Sets up your push notifications 
    setupPush();
}

// Fires when device is ready.
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
```